# $\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor + 1 \ \neq \lceil\log_2(x)\rceil?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, computer-science, binary

> Is there any case where $$\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor + 1 \ \neq \lceil\log_2(x)\rceil ?$$

I'm in discrete mathematics, and my teacher stated the former formula to be finding how many bits are needed to represent some number $x$.

I asked him what the difference between the former and latter was, and he said something in regards to boundaries but I didn't have time to ask further.

Comment: $x=2$, or for that matter any $x$ for which $\log_2 x\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** For integers $n$, by definition we have $$\lfloor n \rfloor = \lceil n \rceil.$$

Comment: Ah, okay. I see now, in cases where n is an integer, the equation doesn't work.

Comment: @BinaryLife Yes, that's right. The equation *does* hold for all noninteger, real $n$, though.